# Presto multi cooker sous vide- clarification?

Tags: sous-vide

I read Marc-André LaFortune's post about [using the Presto multi cooker as a secondary sous vide machine](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/4423/4590).

I'm interested in doing this but it would appear to me that the machine is not accurate enough without modification to hold the pot to +/- .7 F.
Do you do this by monitoring temperature with a thermometer and switching it on and off, or with a PID controller like others have used?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technology.

Comment: Equipment is specifically on topic here, so my opinion is that it doesn't need to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The standard hack is to use a PID controller.  IF you google, you will find many articles detailing exactly how, such as this detailed one from [Over Engineered](http://www.over-engineered.com/projects/sous-vide-pid-controller/).

There are now also a couple of vendors of moderately low cost circulators intended specifically for this application such as [Sansair](http://sansaire.com/) that you insert into a pot or cooler.  They are new to the market, so there are some early adopter issues being reported, but the idea is quite elegant.